# Открыть сокет по ссылке+токен python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.x

Есть пример кода на js, как открыть сокет и пример работы с ним. Но на питоне не выходит создать его.. так как в примере отсутствует сервер и порт к которому надо подключиться. Есть только ссылка с токеном для подключение. Скорее всего есть другие способы в питоне, о которых я еще не знаю прошу помощи.

Код:

```
const socketToken = '';

  //Connect to socket
  const data= io(`https://sockets.data.com?token=${socketToken}`);


  data.on('event', (eventData) => {
    if (!eventData.for && eventData.type === '') {     
      console.log(eventData.message);
    }
    if (eventData.for === 'test') {
      switch(eventData.type) {
        case '1':          
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        case '2':
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        default:          
          console.log(eventData.message);
      }
    }.
```

Comment: Смешались в кучу кони, люди... Напишите конкретно, что вам нужно. Вам нужен tcp-клиент на python?

Comment: https://github.com/facundofarias/awesome-websockets#python

Comment: нужно тоже самое на питоне. Для сокета нужен хост и порт. такой информации нет, если только ссылка для подключения. Все

Answer (score 0):

Например, для Питона есть библиотека - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ при помощи которой ты получишь почти аналогичный код. А что касается хоста и порта, так порт для HTTPS известен, если хочется низкоуровневой игры, равно как и хост - из URL-а. Но для "низкоуровневого" варианта будет много возни с OpenSSL, HTTP заголовками и пр.